# Kibana docker image fails to start due to xpack security error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to run the docker image : docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4

Command used to run :

```
docker run -d -e "xpack.monitoring.enabled=false" -e "xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled=false" --name kibana --restart always -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
```

However, it fails to run and gives the following expection :

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-28T08:04:05Z","tags":["fatal"],"pid":8,"message":"\"xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled\" setting was not applied. Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed and enabled."}
FATAL "xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled" setting was not applied. Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed and enabled.
```

xpack is disabled in elasticsearch container as well using the -e flag to disable xpack.

```
docker inspect elastic
```

gives

```
 "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "xpack.security.enabled=false",
                "PATH=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "ELASTIC_CONTAINER=true",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk"
            ],
```

Running kibana without xpack environment variables also doesnt work:

```
docker run -d --name kibana --restart always -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think the `-e "xpack.monitoring.enabled=false"` is enough and you don't need to provide the second one. Have you tried without that?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: what exactly happens when you don't provide the second env? (is there any error ? can you send it ? )

Comment: I get the same error. No change at all.
`{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-10-03T09:49:29Z","tags":["fatal"],"pid":8,"message":"\"xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled\" setting was not applied. Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed and enabled."}
FATAL "xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled" setting was not applied. Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed and enabled.`

Comment: could you change the second one(`"xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled=false"`) to `xpack.monitoring.ui.enabled=false` and retry?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: What exactly do you want from this command? if you don't need xpack at all you can [disable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/disable-plugin.html) its plugin too. or you can use `oss` flavor of kibana (`docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181208/discussion-between-amir-masud-zarebidaki-and-humblecoder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `oss` flavor of kibana which doesn't contain xpack.

```
docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.2.4
```

if you don't want to use `oss` flavor you can remove the plugin by using this command:

```
[ "/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin remove x-pack; /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker" ]
```

or even you can disable the kibana xpack plugin features with providing all needed envs which are more than `monitoring` (it includes `security` and other parts of xpack). 
as @Ignacio Millán said it has a bit different syntax:

```
-e "XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=false"
```

Comment: Since nothing else worker I used the OSS image instead,a and it worked.Thanks! Where do I run the command to remove x-pack?

Comment: if you write your own docker file or kubernetes yaml you can use what I mentioned but without that you can use it in the shell form  (`"/bin/bash -c '/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin remove x-pack; /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker' "`) and provide it at the end of docker run command. which ignores the original cmd of docker and run this one.

Answer (score 1):

### Disable XPack in Kibana

update the environment variables in the configuration

```
  xpack.security.enabled: 'false'
  xpack.monitoring.enabled: 'false'
  xpack.watcher.enabled: 'false'
  xpack.ml.enabled: 'false'
```

Here is the simple yml configuration to disable the xpack in kibana

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  kibana:
      image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.0
      container_name: kibana
      environment:
        # ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
        xpack.security.enabled: 'false'
        xpack.monitoring.enabled: 'false'
        xpack.watcher.enabled: 'false'
        xpack.ml.enabled: 'false'
      ports: 
        - 5601:5601
```

Answer (score 0):

The right environment variables have a different syntax according to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html)

So the command should be:

```
docker run -d -e XPACK_MONITORING_UI_ENABLED=false --name kibana --restart always -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
```

You can also use a YAML file to configure Kibana easier:

```
docker run -d -v `pwd`/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml --name kibana --restart always -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
```

Comment: Capital env variables dont work. I had tried that as well. And I wanted avoid mounting the yml file to avoid any external dependencies that we have to provide to the deployment team. Pulling the image should make it work.

Comment: OK, the variables were wrong, it works with just XPACK_MONITORING_UI_ENABLED=false. Just edited the answer